# Long Table containing figures ,equations and multicolumn

Tags: tables, floats, equations, longtable

I want to make a long table (3 to 4 pages) of 5 columns containing its name, figure, equation, advantages, and disadvantages

But when I am using longtable package and other helping material from the web, I am not able to get the desired table, although various errors occurred

Here is the shortcode

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
% \usepackage[left=0.2cm, right=1cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}

\caption{Overview of papers including Image Compression Based On Deep 
Learning Techniques} \label{tab:long} \\
\hline
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Activation }} &\multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\textbf{Figure}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Equation}} & \multicolumn{1} 
 {c}{\textbf{Advantage}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Advantage}}

   %& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
 \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{c}%
  {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
  \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Equation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c} 
    {\textbf{Advantage}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Advantage}}
    % \hline
     % & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
   % \endhead

      % \hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
     % \endfoot

     \hline 
   \endlastfoot
   \hline
         % \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{CNN Based Architectures}} \\ 
      % \hline
     \textbf{Sigmoid}\cite{sigmoid} 1995 & \includegraphics[width=20mm] 
     {sigmoid1.jpg}
    & $\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$  & Squashes numbers in the range [0,1] 
   & \begin{itemize} \item Causes saturation by killing the gradients \item 
      Not zero centered which makes it impracticable to use \item Exponential function is a bit expensive function making it infeasible to use in practice \end{itemize} \\ 


     end{longtable}



    \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

Please help me how to make long table having equation figure and other descriptions together

[image]

Answer (score 4):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo,               % in real document remove option "demo"
            export]{adjustbox}  % added
\usepackage{makecell,           % added
            longtable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small} % added
\renewcommand\theadgape{}                % added
\usepackage{enumitem}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \small                              % for better fit text into cells
    \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth} % that caption width is equal to table width
    \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,          % itemize setup
                        leftmargin = *,
                        before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells                  % for additional vertica space around cells' contents  
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}  % all images will have width equal to cell's widths
    \begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{\dimexpr0.16\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.2\arrayrulewidth}|}
                       *{2}{p{\dimexpr0.26\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.2\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\caption{Overview of papers including Image Compression Based On Deep Learning Techniques}
\label{tab:long}    \\
    \hline
\thead{Activation}  & \thead{Figure}        & \thead{Equation}
                    &  \thead{Advantage}    & \thead{Disadvantage}    \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{Overview of papers including Image Compression Based On Deep Learning (cont.)}            \\
\thead{Activation}  & \thead{Figure}        & \thead{Equation}
                    &  \thead{Advantage}    & \thead{Disadvantage}    \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hline
   \endlastfoot
\textbf{Sigmoid}\cite{sigmoid} 1995
    & \includegraphics[valign=t]{sigmoid1.jpg}
        & $\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$
            & Squashes numbers in the range [0,1]
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Causes saturation by killing the gradients
                \item   Not zero centered which makes it impracticable to use
                \item   Exponential function is a bit expensive function making it infeasible to use in practice
                    \end{itemize}           \\
    \end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: Thanks, but still figure is black, its a black box, when I tried on my own document

Comment: if you would read code carefuller, you would see `usepackage[demo,    % remove in real document`, meaning, that `demo` option should not be used in real document. it generate black rectangle instead real image, which i haven't.

Comment: @DiptiMishra, you are welcome. however, if answer fulfill all your expectation, you can accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer.) :-)

Comment: @DiptiMishra, i add some more comments to code. they should explain what for are some code lines.

Comment: Hi, when i degined that table in separate file, it was perfect, but when i am placing that code in my original document which is following double column format, the table also come in same format ,,half of the page in every page is blank verticaly

Comment: @DiptiMishra, long table doesn't work in two column documents. in your question is not mentioned, that you have such a document. you had to be more clear and specifics. to solve this new problem is the best to ask new question (and first accept this one, it perfectly solve asked problem!). for example, one possible solution is in place of table change two column format into one column, but his is tricky.